# How to scan a "0" on the months that have one digit?

Tags: c, slash

I am doing this C program where I need to input a date and see whether it is a valid date. However, I do not know how to scan a "0" in front of the days and months that have one digits. Also, the program requires to scan "/" as well. If the user inputs "07-14-1999" it has to be invalid because the user did not input "/". What should I do with these two problems? The following is the code I have so far. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int day, month, year;
    printf("Please enter a date to check validity (in the form of MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    scanf("%i%i/%i%i/%i%i",&month, & month, &day, &day, &year, &year, &year &year);


    printf("%i%i/%i%i/%i%i",month, month, day, day, year, year, year, year);


}
```

Comment: @user3121023 hello, it does not work. when I input 08/12/1990, it gives me 0/45/53, and when I input 01/01/1990, it only gives me 1/1/1990

Comment: Florence, if you scanf for `&year, &year, &year, &year` your are having the variable `year` assigned FOUR TIMES TO! Please read more about scanf and about integer veriables.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Hey I am really new to C programming. This is literally my second program with C. I honestly have no idea what to do. Would you give me some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Florence, best thing is to read a book on C or google for an on-line course and do the excercises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to scan three integer numbers, so you should use `%d` once for each number in `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
```

To validate input it makes sense to check number of successfully scanned integers:

```
int res = scanf("%2d/%2d/%4d", &month, &day, &year);
if (res != 3) {
     /* error */
}
```

Here `%2d` means that the max length of that input integer is 2 digits.
If everything is scanned correctly you can validate ranges for month, day and year.

To print leading zero:

```
printf("%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
```

Here `%02d` means that the integer is printed by minimum two symbols and zero is prepended if there is only one symbol.

---

It is trickier to make sure that the number of input symbols is correct. The above scan pattern also accepts date "1/1/1999". To simplify and to avoid scanning each symbol separately it is possible to read input as a string:

```
int day, month, year;
/* buffer length is enough for 10 date symbols + 1 null terminating
 * character + 1 for too long input */
char buf[12];
char dummy_end_test;

printf("Please enter a date to check validity (in the form of MM/DD/YYYY): ");

/* scan as a string with maximum field width 11, check that the number
 * of input characters is exactly 10 */
if (scanf("%11s", buf) != 1 || strlen(buf) != 10) {
    printf("incorrect input length\n");
    return 1;
}

/* parse integer numbers from string
 * try to read symbol dummy_end_test to filter input as 11/1/19999 or 11/11/199x
 * if it is possible to read one more character after four digits of year
 * the number of scanned entries is 4 that is invalid input */
int ret = sscanf(buf, "%2d/%2d/%4d%c", &month, &day, &year, &dummy_end_test);

if (ret != 3) {
    printf("error\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Here I used `sscanf` that scans formatted input from string.

Anyway it is needed to validate ranges for day, month and year. All those numbers must be greater than 0. Maximum day depends on month and/or on leap year.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But do you know how to test if the user input "0" for months and days that have only one digits?

Comment: My reading of the question is that the OP wants to parse exactly DD/MM/YYYY. The code as presented will accept incorrect input. Such as "1/9/2015" or "001/009/15". Probably should include width specifiers in the `scanf` and check its return value.

Comment: Okay my professor wants the user to input exactly in a format of dd/mm/yyyy . I have to test whether the user inputs two digits for days and months, whether the user inputs "/", and whether it is a valid date.

Comment: @OrestHera I am just wondering what does it mean by "res != 3" ?

Comment: @FlorenceLo To understand how it works you should read manual for those functions: http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf The function `scanf` returns numer of input items successfully matched. So, if everything is successfuly there are 3 scanned numbers, otherwise there is something wrong (no `/` or too more digits entered).

Comment: @OrestHera Thank you.

Comment: @FlorenceLo What do you want for input `1/1/2000`? It is also scanned correctly.

Comment: @OrestHera what do you mean by what do I want for this input? I think this input will be invalid since it does not have two digits for months and days.

Comment: @FlorenceLo With perfect match it is more tricky. I updated the answer by usage of scanning from string.

Comment: @OrestHera Hey, I tried to run your program. It does not work.

Comment: @FlorenceLo What do you mean it does not work? It fails to compile or gives wrong result? You needed to include `#include <string.h>` for `strlen` function.

Comment: @OrestHera I input "1111111" and I got an output of "1111111/45/53"

Comment: @FlorenceLo For too small string you should see "incorrect input length" and exit.

Comment: @OrestHera Sorry my bad. I somehow deleted "main()". It works perfectly fine. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @FlorenceLo It is easy to make a mistake with such scans. I updated solution for one more possible invalid input pattern: "11/1/19999" or "11/1/1999x" or "1/1/1999xx" or even "1/1/19xx". It is needed to make sure that all 10 characters are parsed as month, day, year and there are no redundant characters at the end.